# About pandas's DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

I changed a DataFrame's columns, Pycharm give me a message `"nothing to show"`, but it can show at the panel before I changed.

I changed the columns to a list fill with "a".
I tried one single example, a bit of `data: {"x": [1, 2, 3], "y": [2, 3, 4]}`

```
import pandas as pd
It works:
data = pd.DataFrame({"x": [1, 2, 3], "y": [2, 3, 4]})
data.columns = ["u", "t"]
```

it shows at the panel.

Comment: There is no a special character in my columns including the changed columns.

Comment: Please show us exactly what doesn't work. From what I understand of your question, all code that you posted actually works.